# Windows Azure Virtual Machine - IIS logs

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, azure, azure-storage

We have created a Windows server 2012 virtual machine is Azure and deployed ASP.NET MVC website in IIS. Right now, we have enabled IIS logging and its saving log files on local disk.

Is there any way by which we can save IIS logs to Azure blob storage or table storage?

There are lot of articles about how to do this in web role OR in Azure Web Site, but not for IIS in manually created virtual machine.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to write a process to export them to external storage. Web Roles use the azure PaaS agent which isn't currently available in IaaS. Web Sites are a higher level service built on PaaS so the agent is available there already.

If you poke around, I'm sure there are several sample projects already available that will help with this.